# Creating a background worker class with Func and Action

Tags: c#, generics, action, func

Hi I have created this class to easily allow me to do some work in the background however I am struggling to get it to work

```
public static class UtilityHelper
{
    private static void AssignWork<T>(this BackgroundWorker bw, Func<T> work, Action<T> completionWork = null)
    {
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate(object obj, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                args.Result = work.Invoke();
            });
        if(completionWork != null)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object obj, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                completionWork.Invoke((T)args.Result);
            });
        }
    }

    public static void RunWorkAsync<T>(Func<T> work, Action<T> completionWork = null)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.AssignWork<T>(work, completionWork);

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to be able to just call `UtilityHelper.RunWorkAsync` passing in the methods as actions and func's.
The RetrieveKnownPrinters method returns DataTable and the UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters has one parameter of DataTable.

I am trying to call it like `UtilityHelper.RunWorkAsync<DataTable>(() => RetrieveKnownPrinters(), () => UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters());`

However I am getting error Error    110 Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 0 arguments because Action of T takes one argument however I cannot pass an argument with .Invoke if i just use Action. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: change:
UtilityHelper.RunWorkAsync(() => RetrieveKnownPrinters(), () => UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters());

to:

UtilityHelper.RunWorkAsync(() => RetrieveKnownPrinters(), result => UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters());

Comment: `Action<T> completionWork` means that the action must take one argument but in your calling function, your action doesn't take any arguments (`() => UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters()`)

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is obsolete. Anything it does can be done with the TPL in an easier way. You probably need a single loop and a `Progress<T>`. If you want one class to process messages in the background though, you should use `ActionBlock<T>`

Comment: Hi @Howwie i should have probably put the signature of the UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters method signature in as well, this method does have one parameter of type DataTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the parameter in the `Invoke()` method. Seems what you need to do is just call your method properly (notice the `p`):

```
UtilityHelper.RunWorkAsync<DataTable>(
        () => RetrieveKnownPrinters(), (p) => UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters(p));
```

**EDIT:** also you may try this

```
UtilityHelper.RunWorkAsync<DataTable>(
        RetrieveKnownPrinters, UpdateDataViewWithKnownPrinters);
```

Comment: How is the p evaluated to the return object of RetrieveKnownPrinters though?

Comment: You can change `p` to anything else no difference, I suggest you to search for lambda expressions in C#